# Environment tag dosent work?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

What is required to get the environment tag to work?

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Style.css" media="screen,projection" />
</environment>
```

Its just rendered just as i wrote it in a `.cshtml` and not filtered based on the Environment i specified.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems you need to add `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"` to the file containing the html, or if you follow the setup of a default project add it to `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

Also make sure you have added `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` to your project.json.

Comment: @mcNux what are you trying to say? (note that this question/answer is 2 years old and things might have changed, but your current comment is somewhat unclear and would not help others who find it)

Comment: You're right. Apologies. I meant that `@addTagHelper ...` must be added to `_ViewImports.cshtml`, not `_ViewStart.cshtml`. I was ignorant of the difference and wondered why adding to the latter didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use .NET CORE 1.0, namespace changes to

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I wasn't using `app.UseStaticFiles();` in my startup